# Interacting with a website and getting data using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to interact with a [website](https://fortiguard.com/webfilter). For my data analysis project, I have a list of 1 million websites and I want to find the category of each website. That is why I am using that website.

Now, I want to automate that process of typing out 1 million websites and getting their category. I want to use python for this. Can anyone please suggest me any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "web scraping". This topic is too general, wide-ranging, context-specific, and opinion-based for Stack Overflow. See this article for an introduction scraping with Python and Beautiful Soup: https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/

Comment: @leepowers will do. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), i.e.:

```
import requests, traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

domains = ["duckduckgo.com", "opensource.com"]
for dom in domains:
    try:
        req = requests.get(f"https://fortiguard.com/webfilter?q={dom}&version=8")
        if req.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
            cat = soup.find("meta",  property="description")["content"].split(":")[1].strip()
            print(dom, cat)
    except:
        pass
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

---

Output:

```
duckduckgo.com Search Engines and Portals
opensource.com Information Technology
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/2cbbe8cdfe)

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. Now, I have got an idea on how to approach this. Thanks for the help.