# Follow up about crawling the website using python

Tags: python-3.x

[Interacting with a website and getting data using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997205/interacting-with-a-website-and-getting-data-using-python)

this is my previous question regarding how to crawl a website using python. I have a follow up question on that

I have a csv file of 1 million websites and I am trying to find the category of each website using the website I have mentioned in my previous post

But the thing is, i have started running the script 1 hour back and till now i got the results of 3000 websites only. So, i guess its gonna take a very long time to get all 1 million websites

Can anyone please suggest a better way to achieve the same task and get the results faster

Answer (score 0):

**Spin up multiple threads/program instances**

I took a look at the answer you accepted. For reference, 3000 websites in an hour is one website every 1.2 seconds. That is not bad for web scraping. Why does each website take 1.2 seconds? Because `requests.get`has to wait for for the website to load before scraping it for the category.

There is very little you can do to speed up the loading of any given website. As a result, you want your computer to be making multiple requests at a time to speed up the process.

If you are a Python beginner, the simplest way is probably break up the list of 1 million websites into several different lists and run multiple instances of the same program against different lists at the same time. You can then merge the list.

The proper way to do it would be to create several threads within the program and have each thread run BeautifulSoup against a section of the list with the results then merged together.